# Raster: if the coordinates exactly match replace the values, if not NA

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'd like to replace the actual raster (`r`) values with new values in (`Class@data$layer`). But, my condition is if the coordinates in raster `r` exactly match with `Class` coordinates (`SpatialPointsDataFrame`), then replace with the new values (`layer`), and all over the coordinates replace with NA. In my example:

```
library(sp)  
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

# create raster
r <- matrix(rnorm(n=10000,mean=10),100,100)
r <- raster(r)
extent(r) <- c(544937,545916,7321332,7322524)
projection(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=22 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# Selection of some coordinates that exists in the raster 
ras.coords <- as.data.frame(coordinates(r))
coords.sample <- ras.coords %>% sample_n(100)

# Create a new values
coords.sample$layer <- rpois(n=100, lambda=25)

# Convert  to SPDF
Class <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coords.sample[,1:2],
                           data = as.data.frame(coords.sample[,3]), 
                           proj4string = crs(r))
names(Class) <-("layer")

#Rewrite raster values, but the values are populated if exist the coordinate correspondence if not replace by NA

r[cellFromXY(r, Class@coords)] <- Class@data$class
```

Obviously doesn't work, but it expresses my goal. Please, any help with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can just do

```
x <- rasterize(Class, r, "layer")
```